# In clause Nodejs snowflake not getting result set

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on snowflake with nodejs. I have used snowflake-sdk.

My raw query is
`select * from xyz where x in ('1','2','3')`.
For this, in node.js, i had written query as `connection.execute({ sqlText: select * from xyz where x in (:1), binds: [] })`
what should I pass in binds and in which format, I am not getting an idea for it?

Answer (score 1):

Note: not compiled or tested the below, but it's based on a technique we've used

It isn't possible to directly bind the array of values, but the following works:

var params = ['1', '2', '3'];
var statement = `select * from xyz where id in (${params.map(x => '?').join()})`;

// statement will now be:
// select * from xyz where id in (?, ?, ?)

connection.execute({ sqlText: statements, binds: params })

Answer (score 0):

Please review the node.js driver documentation which provides a sample for the bind operations : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#binding-statement-parameters

Comment: Hi @Srinath `sqlText: select * from xyz where x in (:1),binds:[[''10','20,'30'']] `. I had written something like this. But that doesn't works. Can't upvote the answer.